# Updating Parent Component state from multiple child components' componentDidMount() synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, children, direction

Ok so this question is a bit tricky. I have been thinking about whether this is even correct concept wise, considering React is supposed to be a one-way flow of data, from parent to children, and not viceversa. But I would like to post the question anyway so I get different opinions and even possibly a way to get this to work.

In my app, I have a pretty large component that accepts forms as its children, and does some nifty React magic to pass its methods to the children so when the children elements are changed, they trigger the parent components methods that store the data in state and handles the form submissions. It works very nicely, however it is not so good at catching "defaultValues".

In a nutshell, I'm trying to trigger my parent method on the chilren's componentidMount() method, and it works, however, if there's more than one child trying to do this, the method gets called twice but it only uses the second child's dataset.

I have created a simplified version of my issue in the following code:

```
import React from 'react'

export class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data : {name:'james'}
        }
        this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this)
    }

    updateData(key,data){
        console.log('updating data')
        this.setState({
            data : {...this.state.data,[key]:data}
        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div>
                <Child1 updateData={this.updateData}/>
                <Child2 updateData={this.updateData}/> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.updateData('child1','myData')
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                I am Child 1
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.updateData('child2','myData2')
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                I am Child 2
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This code will render 'updating data' twice on the console, but it will only update the state with the data sent in child2. Again, I can see how this may not be the best approach considering that im setting the state of a parent from its children, but it would be a good solution for setting default values on a parent component that gets reused a lot with different children.

Im all ears stack overflow

Comment: The good thing to start would be using callback in the `setState` function. `this.setState((prevState) => ({ data: { ...prevState.data, [key]: data } }));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that `setState` does both updates at the same time (batches them) meaning the same initial state is used when merging both partial states. You need to use updater function as shown by *kind user*:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ data: { ...prevState.data, [key]: data } }));
```

Comment: Yeah, I've checked it. It works as expected with callback. Anyways, thanks for publishing my comment ;)

Comment: @kinduser I wanted to write the same code but since you were first I gave you the credit for it ;)

Comment: oh my god it seems so obvious now that you guys mentioned it, haha thanks a lot!